# How redirect by htaccess to https if url containt fbclid parameter and remove it

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cloudflare

I'm trying to remove query parameter `fbclid=1 if url contain it <br> I'm using` cloudflair` and have issue

My curent htaccess

Sampler url:

```
#sample: https://www.example.com/modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=765766&fbclid=abcd#utm_source=iopio

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=News&file=article&sid=(.*)&?fbclid=[^&]+&?(.*)$ [NC]
 #detect cloudflair if ssl set flexi. Web Server to cloudflare by http then cloudflair to browser by https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cdn-Loop} cloudflare [NC]
RewriteRule ^modules\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=%1%2 [R=302,L]
```

The result will redirect to

```
 https://www.example.com/modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=#utm_source=iopio
```

It loosing the query `%1` 
Some thing wrong here??
It must be:

```
https://www.example.com/modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=765766&fbclid=abcd#utm_source=iopio
```

Please advice's
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may use this rule in your site root .htaccess as top most rule:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cdn-Loop} cloudflare [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?fbclid=[^&]*(?:&(.*))?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^modules\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [R=302,NE,L,NC]
```

Change `302` (temporary redirect) to `301` (permanent redirect) after testing.

Comment: I need to have https in the RewriteRule redirected url , I'v been use your suggestion but it add extra redirect to http then https because cloudflare seting ssl to flexi proxy. have you got any idea thanks :)

Comment: thank you i just add RewriteRule ^modules\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [R=302,NE,L,NC]  then it work

Comment: Sorry I stepped away for some time. Yes that would indeed work and I have updated answer accordingly.